# Select desired columns data from a many to many relation

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pivot-table

I have three tables `employs`, `courses` and `employ_course` (pivot table). I have many columns in `employ` (ex name, emp no, salary etc) and my `course` table has only `id` and `course_name` columns, and my pivot table has `id`, `employ_id` and `course_id`.

This is my view:

```
<table border="1">
   <tr>
     <th>Full name</th>
     <th>Emp no</th>
     <th>salary</th>
     <th>course</th>
   </tr>
   @foreach($data as $item) 
     <tr>
       <th>{{$item['Full_name']}} </th>
       <th>{{$item['emp_no']}}</th>
       <th>{{$item['salary']}}</th>
       <th>{{$item['course_name']}}</th>
     </tr>
    @endforeach
 </table>
```

This is my `employ` model class:

```
class employ extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function courses() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(course::class, 'employ_course');
    }
}
```

This is my `course` model class:

```
class course extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function employs() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(employ::class, 'employ_course');
    }
}
```

And this is my `employ_course` model class:

```
class employcourse extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = [];
}
```

This is the code in my controller:

```
public function show()
{
    $data = employ::with('course')->get();
    return view('teacher.teacher_data', compact('data'));
}
```

I only want to show some specific columns from `employ` table like `fullname`, `salary`, `emp no` etc and course name only in my view blade in the form of table.

Comment: This didnt help

Comment: What you call a "pivot table", appears to actually be a `m:m` relationship table.

Comment: yes i make m:m relation and save data on mysql  and i make employ_id as an  foreign key to employ table id coloumn  and i want to get specific coloumn from employ model and course model @CBroe

Answer (score 0):

### Problems

You need to fix your models:
When creating a many to many relationship you should pay attentions Which class belongs and which class has many relations:

**Employ model `belongsTo()`**

```
class employ extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public $timestamps=false;

    protected $guarded=[];

    public function courses(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(course::class, 'employ_course'); // The employ belongs to course
    }
    
}
```

**Course model `hasMany()`**

```
class course extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public $timestamps=false;

    protected $guarded=[];


    public function employs(){
        return $this->hasMany(employ::class, 'employ_course'); // courses has many employees
    }
}
```

Update your controller to this:

```
public function show()
    {
        $datas = employ::with('course')->select('fullname', 'salary', 'emp_no')->get();
        return view('teacher.teacher_data', compact('datas'));
    }
```

the `select()` method will extract the specific field of targeted model directly. i.e., it will select the desired fields from `employ` having relation with `course` read more about [select](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#select-statements)

### Update

Select the columns from other table and return the collection instead of calling `contact()`:

```
public function show()
    {
        $datas = employ::with(['course' => function ($query) {
            $query->select('column_from_course_table');
            }])
        ->select('fullname', 'salary', 'emp_no')->get();
        return view('teacher.teacher_data', ['datas' => $datas]); // return
    }
```

the query inside this `with()` will select the column from `course` table. In your results now you will be able to fetch this by following this syntax in your view:

`$dats->course->column_from_course_table // i.e., course_name`

As `updated syntax`:

```
@foreach($datas as $item) 
     <tr>
       <th>{{$item->Full_name}} </th>
       <th>{{$item->emp_no}}</th>
       <th>{{$item->salary}}</th>
       <th>{{$item->course->course_name}}</th> // Edit this line
     </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: This help it but still i cant get the course name that i make m:m relation of employ with course

Comment: i also want to show the course name with them

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: This error came str_contains(): Argument #1 ($haystack) must be of type string, Closure given

Comment: try the new update and let me know what you think.

Comment: same error came 'str_contains(): Argument #1 ($haystack) must be of type string, Closure given'

Comment: Hey, I made a mistake in my answer try changing the arguments inside the ```with()``` to following: 
```with(['course' => function ($query){$query>select('column_from_course_table'); }])``` 
It was a mistake, I forgot to add a closure to the arguments of with you can see the **[]**

Comment: This came Attempt to read property "course_name" on null

Comment: well, that's a good news, your query works now. Try using it with ```with('course')``` without function,  and see if it still throws error

Comment: same error is coming 'Attempt to read property "course_name" on null' when i remove course or course name from this $item->course->course_name the table came without course

Comment: this means the problem is with your relation. The answer completely fulfils your initial question.